# Positioning of checkbox inside label hidden/shown during hover or selected

Tags: html, css

I would like to show the checkbox only when the corresponding label is hovered or if it is selected. That's easy, but I'm struggling with positioning the text of my label in a way that doesn't jump to the right when the checkbox is displayed.

```css
label input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

label:hover input[type=checkbox], input[type=checkbox]:checked{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  text
</label>
```

Comment: do you want the label to not move and have the checkbox appear to the right? left? fade out the label and fade in the checkbox?

Comment: @BenSewards Checkbox to the left of the label, fading in/out can be added later, but only for the checkbox..

Comment: is putting the checkout to the right side an option? that will just make it appear and not touch your text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `visibility` property instead of display.

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
<style>
    label input[type=checkbox] {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    label:hover input[type=checkbox],
    input[type=checkbox]:checked {
        visibility: visible;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> text
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use visibility inplace of display like as per below :

```
<style>
    label input[type=checkbox] {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    label:hover input[type=checkbox], input[type=checkbox]:checked {
        visibility:visible;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a few of options:

1. make the checkbox on the right of the text, this way the text doesn't move.
2. use Opacity rather than Visibility (visibility is not supported by some browsers)
3. animate the checkbox so the text slides to the right (so set the width (or max-width) of the checkbox to `0` with overflow hidden, and then update it with a transition)

opacity: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/ghogvcsx/1/

animated: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/ghogvcsx/

```
<label>
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </span>
  text
</label>

label span {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-width 0.3s linear;
}

label:hover span {
  max-width: 30px;
  transition: max-width 0.3s linear;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution is to insert your text first then checkbox. Add css to prettify it.

```
<label>
  text
  <input type="checkbox">
</label>
```

Comment: But what if he want to put checkbox first?

Comment: label input[type=checkbox] {
      display: none;
      position:absolute;
    }
    label span {
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
    label:hover input[type=checkbox], input[type=checkbox]:checked{
      display: inline;
    }
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span>text</span>
    </label>

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code
Check this:
    label input[type=checkbox] {
      display: none;
      position:absolute;
    }
    label span {
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
    label:hover input[type=checkbox], input[type=checkbox]:checked{
      display: inline;
    }

Your code:
    
      
      text

```css
    label input[type=checkbox] {
      display: none;
      position:absolute;
    }
    label span {
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
    label:hover input[type=checkbox], input[type=checkbox]:checked{
      display: inline;
    }
```

```html
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span>text</span>
    </label>
```